# Can I use an IF statement in an SQL file to check whether a database is selected?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have an SQL file `commands.sql` full of SQL commands. The intention is that the user may run the commands in the file by using the `SOURCE` command as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/batch-commands.html). But it is assumed that the user has selected a database. If the user has not selected a database, then they will see a large number of "No database selected" errors.

Is there a way to use the `IF` statement to check whether a database is selected, as in

```
IF a database is selected THEN
    (statements)
ELSE
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You need to select a database';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since scripts abort upon the first error that they encounter (unless invoked with the `force` option), one can achieve a certain degree of flow-control using  prepared statements:

```
SET @sql := IF(
  DATABASE() IS NULL,
  "SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You need to select a database'",
  "DO SELECT NULL"
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

(However, I don't think the `SIGNAL` command can be executed via a prepared statement).

Comment: Correct (at time of writing), but you get an error `ERROR 1295 (HY000) at line 12 in file: 'ScriptMyErrorCheck.sql': This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Answer (score 0):

`IF ... THEN ...` can only be used in stored procedures or functions, not in simple queries. You would have to create a stored procedure and run that from your SQL file.

To check whether a database is selected you can do something like:

```
SELECT @is_selected:=database();
IF @is_selected IS NULL THEN ...
```